# Postgresql query within a bash script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, postgresql, psql

We are having an issue with a postgresql bash query. The output of the query from the bash script add's additional quotes around the date. Please can you help me fix it?!

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

lastmonth=$(date -d "-1 month -$(($(date +%d)-1)) days" +%Y-%m-%d)
thismonth=$(date -d '-1 month -12 days' +%Y-%m-%d)

sudo -u postgres psql -d linetest_uptime -A -o /tmp/linetest_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt -c "select t.*, ip,port from line_test t,service_address s where '$thismonth' <= start and start < '$lastmonth' and service_address_id=s.id order by t.start,status desc" >/dev/null 2>&1 && sudo mv /tmp/linetest_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt /reporting/line_test_data/ && sudo chown $USER:$USER /reporting/line_test_data/linetest_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt
```

Output is:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d linetest_watchdog -A -o /tmp/linetest_2014-03-13.txt -c 'select t.*, ip,port from line_test t,service_address s where '\''2014-02-01'\'' <= start and start < '\''2014-02-01'\'' and service_address_id=s.id order by t.start,status desc
```

We need to remove the '\' '\' which is now being wrapped around the date variable.

Comment: Have you tried using sed ?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like output from your commands - is it some debug output instead?

What you have looks correct, in that it could be fed into the shell and give what you asked for.  Note that `'aaa'\''bbb'` is identical to `"aaa'bbb"`!

Side note: your variables look a bit overcomplicated, and you repeat `$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`; the following may help:

```
lastmonth=$(date -d "-1 month" +%Y-%m-01)
thismonth=$(date +%Y-%m-01)
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

and the SQL query may be more idiomatic as `... where date between '$lastmonth' and '$thismonth' ...`.